# Angular 2 Different modules same routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am having two main routes, both loading same child module. Is there any possible way to have two routes with same name on the child module that loads two different components with respect to the main route.

**Main Routes**:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [{
    path: 'first',
    loadChildren: './features/common#CommonModule',
    canActivate: [AppAuthGuard]
}, {
    path: 'second',
    loadChildren: './features/common#CommonModule',
    canActivate: [AppAuthGuard]
}]
```

Now I'm expecting the common module to have routes something like this

```
export const routes = [{
        path: 'list', component: FirstListComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
    },{
        path: 'list', component: SecondListComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
    }]
```

So, I want something like

- If route is *first/list*, then *FirstListComponent* should be loaded.
- If route is *second/list*, then *SecondListComponent* should be loaded.

I know that the order of the routes matters. And the proposed way is not possible. Can anyone suggest any possible way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Please set path like this

```
export const routes = [{
        path: 'first/list', component: FirstListComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
    },{
        path: 'second/list', component: SecondListComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
    }]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But if I use like this, then the total route will be *first/first/list* and *second/second/list* respectively.

Comment: @Teja:Please refer routing document of angular https://angular.io/guide/router#child-routing-component. so you will get better idea on routing.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, and is more simple:

App routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'mobile',
    loadChildren: './view/mobile/mobile.module#MobileModule',
    canActivate: [MobileGuardService],
    data: {
      preload: false
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'desktop',
    loadChildren: './view/desktop/desktop.module#DesktopModule',
    canActivate: [DesktopGuardService],
    data: {
      preload: false
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'error',
    loadChildren: './view/error/error.module#ErrorModule',
    data: {
      preload: false
    }
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: window.innerWidth < 768 ? `/mobile/etc/etc/etc` : `/desktop/etc/etc/etc`,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: window.innerWidth < 768 ? `/mobile/etc/etc/etc` : `/desktop/etc/etc/etc`
  }
];
```

Mobile Guard

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MobileGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {
  }

  canActivate() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {
      this.router.navigate(['/']).then();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

Desktop Guard

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DesktopGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {
  }

  canActivate() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
      this.router.navigate(['/m/']).then();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

I do this way, becuase `redirectTo` make problems with guards :(

:)