# Angular 5 : Different router-outlet in different modules + lazy loading

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have two modules and each have a routing module file and a router-outlet within their html.
I want to load components depending in which module I am.

My file tree look like this:

```
project
|-- module2
|-- -- profil
|-- -- - profil.component.html 
|-- -- - profil.component.ts
|-- -- - profil.component.spec.ts
|-- -- - profil.component.css
|-- -- module2-routing.module.ts
|- module1-routing.module.ts
|- module1.module.ts
|- module1.component.ts
|- module1.component.spec.ts
|- module1.component.css
```

I have the following files:

**module1-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'module2', loadChildren: './module2/module2.module#Module2Module' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class Module1RoutingModule { }
```

**module1.component.html**

```
<router-outlet name="m1"></router-outlet>
```

**module2-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProfilComponent } from './profil/profil.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'profil', component: ProfilComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class Module2RoutingModule { }
```

**module2/home.component.html**

```
<div id="module2-home">

  <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet name='m2'></router-outlet>

</div>
```

I tried to use the outlet option (example: { path: 'profil', component: ProfilComponent, outlet: 'm2' } ) in my routing files, but got this error :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'
```

Comment: The outlet configuration should be in the component with the outlet inside, what means: { path: '', component: HomeComponent, outlet: 'm2' }

Comment: I tried this and it just give me a blank page, components are not added

Comment: Can you provide some repo with a little reproduction, maybe using stackblitz ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// appRouting-routing.module.ts
        const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
      {
        path: 'modules', component: ModulesComponent,
        children: [
          { path: 'module1', component: Module1Component, children: Module1_ROUTE },
          { path: 'module2', component: Module2Component, children: Module2_ROUTE }
        ]
      }
    ];


    //export your child routes from your module1 and module2 routing.ts files
    //example:
   export const Module1_ROUTE: Routes = [
        { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
    ];
```

refer child routes [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#child-routing-component). This will resolve your problem.

Comment: Please confirm if my answer helps you.

Comment: Sorry, i didnt have the time to test it before.
It works perfectly, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

To avoid ambiguity, Use your module name in path for your routes in such a way that no two routes have the same path. Hope this will solve your problem.Refer
[Angular 2 Different modules same routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663700/angular-2-different-modules-same-routing)

Comment: If i try this, my routes will look like "/module2/module2/profil" and not "/module2/profil", and the first option can't work because there is no path define for the route. My html look like this (in module2) : <a class="nav-link" href="/merserin/profil">Profil</a>

Comment: Are you trying to render both modules simultaneously?

Comment: The first module render the second, and i would like the second to render a component

Comment: you need to use child routes to achieve this. check below answer.